# Ember.js - Can the root url link to two routes, one for authenticated users and one for guests?

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible for the root path, `example.com`, to display a landing page(`application/index`) for not logged in users but a profile page (`users/show`) for users who are logged in?

```
Guest user -> example.com -> application/index

Authenticated user -> example.com -> users/show
```

I know that this goes against Ember's philosophy of the app state being reflected by the url, still, does anyone know if/how this situation is possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do it. Firstly, you should check the user logged in or not in "beforeModel" of "application" route. If user is logged in then transits it to "profile" page using "transitionTo" method otherwise transits it to "login" page.

```
beforeModel: function(transition) {
    var user;
    //put here method to check if user is logged in or not
    if (!user) {
      //if no user then transist to login
      this.transitionTo('login');
    } else {
      //other wise to profile page
      this.transitionTo('profilePage');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jyoti. I should have been a bit clearer maybe. I'm asking if it is possible for the root page to link to these two routes **without** a redirect. e.g The Url for the `users/show` route **is** `example.com`. It's really easy to set up rails routes in this way so I was looking to see if Ember could do the same. In the meantime I'll use your strategy of redirecting